# Android Studio - cloned, 3rd party module after upstream merge on the git remote

Tags: git, android-studio, gradle, parse-platform

[Importing to your project](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android#importing-into-your-app) is routine 'how to' for using 3rd party module. But it leaves open the process i would follow to get into the actual project the result of merged, upstream git?

When i follow the instructions ( clone the 3rd party code then, import a portion of that cloned project ) I get a full copy in the target project. ( now have 2 copies of portions of the original 3rd party project and only 1 of them is connected to the git, remote master ).

Then, at a later date, if i go to where i cloned the 3rd party project and do a git merge upstream in order to pull revisions from the git remote. I will now have stale , unmerged version of the 3rd party code in my project.

So what todo then?? I want the result to be sort of like re-importing the module to the target project.

Do i just make a note to myself where i originally made the git-clone that it was used via 'import module' in another project and that i should got re-import it to that project?

Answer (score 0):

I will clone the project from git first and import it as a module into my project.

To clone a GIT repository, I will first clone it via VCS -> Checkout from Version Control -> Git. Then the project will be cloned into Android Studio Projects Directory.

Then I will open my project currently working. Select File -> Import Module and select the project just cloned.